# apply same jquery function to element present inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

code        [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s21o4gs/2/)

I applied jquery's click function to '`li#info`' element. But when I click, it perform jquery to element of different parent also `('#theme div#info-overlay')`.

I want, whenever '`li#info`' is clicked on the **parent element**`('#theme')` then it perform function to its **child element only**`(div#info-overlay)`.

**Like in the code**, by clicking on 'Fe' it open overlay on both the block. But i want it to show overlay only to the block for which 'Fe'is clicked.

sorry, I am new in jquery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6s21o4gs/4/ check this. But i strongly recommend not to use same id for different elements. Use class instead.

Comment: @Naruto ok, thank you so much. I will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your point. you just need to change one line of code
because both divs have same ids thats why both are appearing on click
and it's not a good practice to use same id multiple time on a single file. 
it will make issue somewhere sometime.

i have change this line

`$("div#info-overlay").toggle('100');`

into this

`$(this).parents('#theme').find("#info-overlay").toggle('100');`

```
check this
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s21o4gs/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use this to find div   `$(this).parents('#theme').find("#info overlay").toggle('100');`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div#theme").hover(function(){

        $(".theme .header *").show();
        $(".theme .header .overlay").hide();
    },function(){
     $(".theme .header *").hide();
    });
 
        $("li#info").click(function(){
          $(".theme .header .overlay").hide();
           $(this).parents('#theme').find("#info-overlay").toggle('100');
        
     
        // $("div#info-overlay").toggle('100');
        });
      
});
```

```css
/*
 theme block
*/
.theme{
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 20px auto;
}
.theme .header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #eee;
}
.theme .header *{
 display: none;
}
.theme .header .overlay{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #fff;
 left: 60px;
 top: 10px;
 width: 83%;
 height: 180px;
 z-index: 80;
}
.theme .header .about{
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}
.theme .header .about li{
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #FED200;
 opacity: .5;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 margin: 5px 0;
}

.theme .footer{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
.theme .footer .left{
 width: 85%;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width:620px) {
 .theme{
  width: 70%;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width:720px) {
 .theme{
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width:920px) {
 body .container.theme-holder {
  width: 70%;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
 body .container.theme-holder {
  width: 95%;
 }
 .theme{
  width: 32%;
 }

}
@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
 body .container.theme-holder {
  width: 85%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theme" class="theme">
   <div class="header">

    <div class="about">
     <li id="info">Fe</li>
    </div>



    <div id="info-overlay" class="overlay">
    info
    </div>

   </div>
   <div class="footer">
    <div class="left">
     <div class="name">
     <p>Corporate sdfsfdsfdsfsd</p>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>


  <div id="theme" class="theme">
   <div class="header">

    <div class="about">
     <li id="info">Fe</li>
    </div>

    <div id="info-overlay" class="overlay">
    info
    </div>

   </div>
   <div class="footer">
    <div class="left">
     <div class="name">
     <p>Corporate dfsasdfdsafs</p>
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
```